# Msi Ge70 Realtek RTL8723AE Missing Wireless 802.11b/g/n Mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, network-adapter, wireless-adapter

I've installed latest ver of Realtek RTL8723AE 2013.12.331.2016 for Msi ge70 2oe laptop on windows 10x64 but missing ieee 802.11 b/g/n mode in driver details. Main issue is that internet speed is up to 20mbps overall and there is a hesitation during speed test.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked at two machines here:  one with AC wireless and one with AX wireless.

Both show 802.11 a/b/g .  The older machine shows 802.11 n/ac and the newer machine shows 802.11 n/ac/ax. Both have a pull down to set the value. I just use the default value.

Since the properties are different by machine and therefore by wireless card, I expect your card is controlling what you see in properties.

It is also possible that the card properties shown are dependent on the operating system used.  I am using Windows 11 here and the cards are Intel cards.

In your case (screen shot above) look in 802.11d to see if it has additional properties.

If not, that is what your card provides you.

You can also ask Realtek Support

Comment: There is only disabled/enabled options in 802.11d, it's disabled. MSI say in specifications that it has 802.11 b/g/n mode. (https://www.msi.com/Laptop/ge70-2oe/Specification) Didn't exist before in windows 8.1.

Comment: It must be a Realtek issue. I am using Windows 11 on my machines here. Still, it is card dependent on within the operating system used.

Comment: Someone must have faced this but no enough entry, what should be do?

Comment: There is no settings for this so you may wish to contact Realtek Support